# Proof that configuration is either stable or oscillates

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are $4$ boxes with marbles in them. In a single sequence, if a box has more $3$ or more marbles, one marble will be given to each of the $3$ other boxes. If it has less than $3$, it does not give out any marbles. A configuration is stable if no further changes in amount of marbles in each box occur. It *oscillates* if the number of marbles cycle through a finite set of combinations, returning to an original configuration. For example, a starting configuration of $[7, 2, 2, 2]$ becomes stable as it becomes $[4, 3, 3, 3]$ after one sequence. However, $[4, 4, 2, 2]$ oscillates between itself and $[2, 2, 4, 4]$.

I know that a configuration is stable iff each box has $3$ or more marbles, or if each box has less than $3$ marbles.

I am interested in proving

1. Each configuration is eventually stable or eventually oscillates
2. If the total number of marbles is more $\ge 15$, any configuration will reach a stable configuration
3. What is the maximum value of k where a combination oscillates k times to its original form

Perhaps one could start by finding the properties of oscillating configuration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are at most $4^k$ possible states (corresponding to each of $k$ marbles having $4$ choices of starting box) so after $4^k$ transitions you are guaranteed to have hit a repeat state. Thus, every starting state has an eventual period of at most $4^k$. In the case of a steady-state, the period is $0$. A period greater than $0$ is an oscillation.

For your second question, my key insight was noticing that if $[21,a,b,c]$ halts in $6$ or less steps (regardless of what $a$, $b$, $c$ are) then $[21+x,a,b,c]$ will also halt for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$. This is because after $6$ steps there will be at least $3+x$ marbles left in the first box and we will have reached a steady-state solution. Thus, I simply checked how long it took every combination of marbles and boxes to halt with the stipulation that they satisfied the following conditions

$$-\text{ There were at least }15\text{ marbles total}$$

$$-\text{ The most amount of marbles a box could start with was }21$$

In total, there were $21$ such arrangements of marbles that took $6$ turns to halt and no arrangements of marbles halted in $7$ or more turns. Since $[5, 4, 3, 2]$ is constructed with $14$ marbles and does not halt, we may conclude that $15$ is the smallest number such that starting with that many marbles guarantees a stead-state solution.

Comment: Why do configurations in [21, a, b, c] always halt in 6 or less steps?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a deep reason, I simply checked every case where the maximum number of starting marbles in a box was $21$ and all four boxes had at least $15$ marbles total. None halted in more than $6$ steps.